# Chinese character encoding in search URL

Tags: java, encoding, character, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to build a search request for elasticsearch in my android app. Below are my codes:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    ElasticSearchAPI searchAPI = retrofit.create(ElasticSearchAPI.class);
    HashMap<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
    headerMap.put("Authorization", Credentials.basic("user", elasticSearchPassword));

    String searchString = "title:"+ title;
    Call<HitsObject> call = searchAPI.search(headerMap, "AND", searchString);
```

From the elasticsearch response I found that the URL becomes: `url=http://35.xxx.xxx.48//elasticsearch/hashtags/hashtag/_search?default_operator=AND&q=title:%E6%B5%B7%E5%BA%95%E6%8D%9E%E7%81%AB%E9%94%85`

However the `title` I passed in here is a valid Chinese character string. How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Use ```URLDecoder``` to get the original url.

Comment: can you give some more specific instructions? Sorry I am new to this..

Comment: I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you use a utf-8 encoding.

```
String encodedUrl = "http://35.xxx.xxx.48//elasticsearch/hashtags/hashtag/_search?default_operator=AND&q=title:%E6%B5%B7%E5%BA%95%E6%8D%9E%E7%81%AB%E9%94%85";
String originalUrl = URLDecoder.decode(encodedUrl, "utf-8");
System.out.println(originalUrl);
```